# How to remove elevation in Flutter GridView?

Tags: flutter

I have got a GridView and every item has an elevation, how to remove it? Also I am interested how to make spaces between items smaller.

I have got this:

https://i.snag.gy/nklzLB.jpg

And I want something like this : https://i.snag.gy/a071Pc.jpg

Item builder:
`Widget _buildItem() {
    return Center(
      child: Image.asset("assets/images/pizza.png"),
    );
}`

And GridView itself:

`GridView.count(
              addRepaintBoundaries: false,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: List.generate(
                30,
                (index) {
                  return _buildItem();
                },
              ),
)`

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the png files do not include the shadow? According to the code you show there shouldn't be any elevation.

Comment: @chemamolins, lol, thank you so much, png was really with shadow. My fault, sorry and thaks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if not use card there is no elevation element, if use card add elevation: 0.0 this automatic add some space

```
Widget _buildItem() {
    return Card(
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Image.asset("assets/images/pizza.png"),
      ),
    );
}
```

or just add padding

```
Widget _buildItem() {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child:Image.asset("assets/images/pizza.png"),
      )
    );
  }
```